# Calling method that modifies a field while another method that uses that field is executing

Tags: c++

I have a question regarding the outside modification of a running method. 
Given this C++ class:

```
#include <iostream>
class Foo {
   public:
      Foo()
         : runBar(true) {}

      void bar() {
         int i = 0;
         while(this->runBar) {
            std::cout << "Loop " << i++ << std::endl;
         }
         std::cout << "Loop done!" << std::endl;
      }

      void baz() {
         this->runBar = false;
         std::cout << "Field changed!" << std::endl;
      }

   private:
      bool runBar;
};
```

And also given this `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   Foo f;
   f.bar();
   f.baz();
   return 0;
}
```

What happens when the call to `Foo::baz()` is made?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is your compiler broken? You can't execute this, and see for yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only have 1 thread of execution, and you do not have anything to change the `while` loop exit condition in the `bar` function, this code will loop forever. Your `baz` function will never be called.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant to call them from separate threads,
here is an example showing main modified to call the function from within a thread. 
Foo is using a mutext to coordinate activity, like allowing the thread to finish printing before being terminated.
The join prevents termination of main from ending everything prematurely.
If you don't coordinate them in some way such as that, it would not possible to say with certainty what the sequence of events would be. Such is the nature of programming with multiple threads.

Either bar runs first in which case it prints, or else baz runs first in which case bar will not. Either is possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

mutex aMutex; //<--

class Foo {
   public:
      Foo()
         : runBar(true) {}

      void bar() {
         int i = 0;
         while(this->runBar) {
            aMutex.lock(); //<--
            std::cout << "Loop " << i++ << std::endl;
            aMutex.unlock(); //<--
         }
         std::cout << "Loop done!" << std::endl;
      }

      void baz() {
         this->runBar = false;
         aMutex.lock(); //<--
         std::cout << "Field changed!" << std::endl;
         aMutex.unlock(); //<--
      }

   private:
      bool runBar;
};
```

---

```
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   Foo f;

   thread myThread { f.bar() }; //call it in a thread
   f.baz();
   myThread.join(); //<--
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your code, `runBar` is neither atomic nor modified and tested while the mutex is locked.  Trivially, you've locked `aMutex` twice in `baz()`, but the second time's obviously meant to be `unlock`....

Comment: good catch. I updated it so that it locks and unlocks. I didn't put runBar in the mutex, I only made the prints atomic. You have to be a little bit careful, when you put runBar in there, not to hog it

Comment: One could leave off the mutex, it only serves the purpose of allowing the prints to be complete (and it shows that one has to manage that sort of thing when multi-thread programming). As far as what happens. Either bar runs first in which case it prints, or else baz runs first in which case bar will not